# Not sure if my 10 threads are reading the same .txt files when they are started

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 10 threads that are started when my java class is started and they look into a directory and start looking for files . In one of my methods I change the .txt files extension to .working which indicates that a file is currently in process . When my java class is invoked or started I see sometimes only 5 files are being processed since their extension is .working . Kindly let me know how should I make sure that no 2 threads are calling the same .txt file !!

Comment: wouldn't starting 10 different threads for this purpose introduce race conditions?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach is to read the list of files in *one* thread, then use a thread-safe producer/consumer queue (e.g. [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)) to publish these "files to process". The ten threads will then all take items off the same queue, which ensures that no item is processed twice.

Comment: This way, you won't have to go into renaming files either.

Comment: Yes, that's just dandy.  My guess is that the OP has been reading that textbook that says 'To use threads in Java, you must create them with parameters, start them and wait for them to finish with join() to get results'.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into a race condition similar to the following pseudo code.  Multiple threads will make the exists test and then try the rename and process the *same* file.

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
File working = new File("file.working");
if (file.exists()) {
   // race condition may happen at this point
   file.renameTo(working);
   processWorking(working);
}
```

You should synchronize around the test and rename.  Something like:

```
private final Object lockObject = new Object();
...

boolean process = false;
// lock around the test and the rename
synchronized (lockObject) {
    if (file.exists()) {
       file.renameTo(working);
       process = true;
    }
}
// process the file outside of the lock
if (process) {
    processWorking(working);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code ! I tried using synchronized block before processing the .txt files but instead of having 10 .working files I was having only 1 .working while but with below code it worked the way I wanted .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in you thread program.

```
 try {
        // Get a file channel for the file
        File file = new File("filename");
        FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();

        // Use the file channel to create a lock on the file.
        // This method blocks until it can retrieve the lock.
        FileLock lock = channel.lock();

        // Try acquiring the lock without blocking. This method returns
        // null or throws an exception if the file is already locked.
        try {
            lock = channel.tryLock();
        } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
            // File is already locked in this thread or virtual machine
        }

        // Release the lock
        lock.release();

        // Close the file
        channel.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: You really need give more information then this otherwise it seems you have just pasted some file locking code. How should the OP use this? Is it really necessary to first call `lock` and then immediately again `tryLock`?

Comment: That will lock the file and if another thread has already locked that file then it will not allow that thread to lock the file and it will throw and exception to the user that this file is already in use by another thread or process.

Comment: @MiserableVariable And by the way I have already use this mechanism in my program which is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Bhavik !! Your solution works perfectly with my scenario ! Thanks for the example !!